# How can I create a custom role applicable to an specific resource type?

Tags: azure-active-directory

When I try to add a new role assignment, I can choose among a list of predefined roles for a specific Azure service. For example, below steps show roles available for assignments for an "App Service"

[image]

[image]

Can I create a custom role that is available and applicable to an specific type of azure service (App Service for example) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***I tried to reproduce the same in my environment and got below results:***

**Note** that, you need either **`Owner`** or **`User Access Administrator`** roles to create custom RBAC role.

You can only **limit access** to custom roles at these ***scopes***: management group, subscription and resource group level.

In your scenario, keep all App services in one resource group and create **custom role** within that resource group level.

In order to create **custom role** from scratch, follow below steps:

***Go to Azure Portal -> Resource groups -> Your Resource group -> Access Control (IAM) -> Add custom role***

[image]

I created **custom role** by selecting **`Start from scratch`** option like below:

[image]

In **`Permissions`** tab, select all the **permissions** that you need based on your requirement as below:

[image]

Check whether the type is **Resource group** or not in *Assignable scopes* tab and select **`Review + create`**:

[image]

Once you select **`Review + create`**, validation will be done, and custom role will be created successfully:

[image]

**Note** that, this custom role is ***only*** visible and accessible to the resources present in **`Sri`** resource group like below:

[image]

When I tried to find the **same role** in resource like Storage account of ***other** resource group*, it is not available like below:

[image]

Comment: This is to create a general custom role. The question is how to create a custom role that apply to "App Services" only. So it won't appear in Azure Storage Access Control roles.

Comment: Then instead of creating it under subscription scope, create it under `resource group` level and select only App service-related permissions while creating role.

Comment: Sorry, not following. Can you elaborate?

Comment: You can create custom role in resource group level like [this](https://i.imgur.com/mPH2QqY.png) so that only resources in that group have access to that role. Make sure to check [Assignable scopes](https://i.imgur.com/iLULjDX.png) tab while creating custom role to limit access.

Comment: @AllanXu You can check the updated answer for more clarity